# Replace whitespaces in a pdf with iText 5

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to replace whitespaces in a pdf with iText 5, if I use both these lines of code:

```
stream.setData(new String(data).replaceAll("\\s+"," ").getBytes());
```

or

```
stream.setData(new String(data).replaceAll(" ","").getBytes());
```

it generates a corrupted pdf.
Full code:

```
  if (object instanceof PRStream) {
            PRStream stream = (PRStream) object;
            byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);

            stream.setData(new String(data).replaceAll("\\s+"," ").getBytes());

        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: maybe `stream.setData(data.replaceAll("\\s+"," ").getBytes());` work with you

Comment: see edit please

Comment: do you want to remove white spaces ?

Comment: You are aware that the stream which you make a string, then replace chars in, then make a byte stream again, (a) not only contains the text that is shown but also many kinds of drawing instructions which your code may damage and (b) the text that is shown is not necessarily encoded in a way your conversion to a string translates correctly, so your code may replace something wrong?

Comment: As mkl hints, your code, or the code in the answer below by @CodeKadiya, is a guaranteed way to generate a corrupted PDF. Are you also aware that what looks as a whitespace, may even not be encoded as a whitespace at all, and that instead drawing instructions are used to put characters at an exact location?

Comment: Please take a step back. Why do you want to replace whitespaces?

Comment: I want to remove whitespaces that divides two words.

Answer (score 0):

change your code as this

```
stream.setData(new String(data).replace(" ","").getBytes());
```

instead of this line

```
stream.setData(new String(data).replaceAll("\\s+"," ").getBytes());
```

Comment: You are aware that the stream which you propose to manipulate differently not only contains the text that is shown but also many kinds of drawing instructions which your code may damage? These instructions usually are separated by white spaces which your proposal attempts to remove without any second thoughts...